# How to use type T of generic in runtime to cast it from one of its non-generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I have a class

```
 class Bar<T>:Foo
 {

   // implements Foo's method
   public Type typeOfGeneric
   {
       get
       {
           return T.class;
       }
   }

 }
```

and in somewhere else, I need to do this:

```
 var test = tmp as Foo;
 var baseObject = (Bar<tmp.typeOfGeneric>)tmp;
```

I know this looks weird but I just wonder if it is possible to cast something to a generic T while not knowing T in run-time and get that T in run-time.

Foo doesn't have type T, Bar has type, I need Foo to return Bar type T to be able to use its own methods.

For example, I can't add this in Foo

```
Bar<T> getCastType{get;}
```

because T is not know to Foo interface.

Comment: See [`typeof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx).

Comment: I tried returning typeof(T) but return value is not usable by casting

Comment: I can't use dynamic. Then I'm stuck here? Should I reconsider making this?

Comment: The point the other post is trying to make is you either need to 1) use known static types, 2) use a generic method, or 3) use runtime reflection to manipulate the code. In your code you can make a reference to `Bar<tmp.typeOfGeneric>` but the known compile time type will be `System.Object`.